# How to use theme_file_link?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

I use the webform_multiple_file for my webform. I want to display webform submissions in a custom view.

I created my **views-view-fields--submissions.tpl.php** and added `print $fields['value_1']->content;` to display images

I want to customize the output. I added this function in my template.php

```
function mytheme_file_link($variables) {
$file = $variables['file'];

// Operates only on files uploaded to webform/invite. Change this to operate on the fields you wish to.
if(strpos($file->uri, 'webform/photos_du_projet')) {
    // Render as thumbnail.
    $url = file_create_url($file->uri);
    $thumbnail = theme('image_style',array(
        'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
        'path' => $file->uri,
        'alt' => t('uploaded image')
    ));
    return '<span class="file">' . $thumbnail. '</span>';
}
else {
    return theme_file_link($variables);
}
```

}

from
[this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1413562#comment-9336763)

But it doesn't work. And if I add `die(print_r($variables));` at the beginning of the function, it does not return anything.

How can I use this function properly? Thank you

Comment: Which theme do your webform submissions use? Usually it’s the admin theme (defaults to Seven)

Comment: It's a custom theme